# Create byte object python

Tags: python

I am trying to create byte object. But it is showing type of created object is `str`

How to create byte object ?

```
>>> z = b"Hello World!"
>>> type(z)
<type 'str'>
>>>
```

Comment: What do you actually want to do with the "bytes object"? As simonzack says, they don't exist in Python. But what exactly are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: In Python 2 `str` **is** the bytes type. The `b` prefix only exists to make writing code compatible with both Python 2 and 3. What problem are you trying to solve here?

Answer (score 0):

You're using python 2. Use python 3 to achieve this.

Comment: Any idea how to in 2. ?

Comment: No, in python 2 they're the same. Instead you have `str` and `unicode`. This is why you should start using python 3. There is however `bytearray`, but that's not the same.